# JestClient Suggest not Working with java.lang.NoSuchMethod Error

Tags: java, elasticsearch, autosuggest, elasticsearch-jest

For all searching, the Jest-client gets initialized with a uri as follows:

```
http://serverIp:serverPort _all/_search
```

How can I initialize a client with a uri, something like following?

```
http://serverIp:serverPort _all/_suggest
```

I am using the following code in a method where Ipas JestClient and a word:

```
String suggestionName = "custom-suggestion-3";

Suggest suggest = new Suggest.Builder("{" +
                                        "  \"" + suggestionName + "\" : {" +
                                        "    \"text\" :" + "\"" + wordToSearch + "\""+
                                        "    \"term\" : {" +
                                        "      \"field\" : \"description\"" +
                                        "    }" +
                                        "  }" +
                                        "}").build();


SuggestResult result = client.execute(suggest);
```

However, it produces an error

> **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.getElasticSearchServer()Ljava/lang/String;**' during client.execute(suggest).

During debugging, I copied the value of **suggest** variable and pasted it into **Sense** and it is working as expected.

I am using the following maven dependency for `_all/_search`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>jest</artifactId>
         <version>0.1.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

The running elastic version is 5.0.1 and for Suggest the following dependency has been imported.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
       <artifactId>jest-common</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` means that there is a version mismatch between your dependencies.  Specifically, somewhere there is an attempt to call a method with signature

```
String getElasticSearchServer()
```

in the `JestHttpClient` class.  This method does not exist in the version of that class that is being used at runtime.

Suggestions:

1. Check what versions of the respective JARs are actually being used.  In particular check that your deployment doesn't have multiple versions of the same JAR.
2. Use the same version for your jest and jest-common dependencies.  From what I can see, they are built and tested as a set with the same version number.
3. Jest version 0.1.2 is ancient.  It looks like it was released in December 2012.  Even 2.0.0 is very old: November 2015.
4. Since you are using ElasticSearch 5.0.1, the correct Jest version should be 5.0.0 or later. Reference: https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest